# Good javascript syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if there's a simple JS syntax highlighter out there?

I don't want line numbers or any WYSIWYG buttons just simple highlighting for MySQL.

I looked at a few and they're all over complicated. I need an editable textarea type box. I also need to be able to get its text with PHP, just like an input box in a form.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a few in the past, here are some good ones.

- http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/
- http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Ace Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about). 
Github, CodeAcademy, KhanAcademy, Cloud9 IDE... All of them use it and it is high performance editor.

Comment: You can't submit Ace in a form

Comment: You need to get raw text or formatted text on server?

Comment: Here's an example: the phpMyAdmin query text box. It highlights the keywords as you're typing. Then you submit the form with that text

Comment: After looking through the Ace API, I found the getValue method

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this - http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/mysql-syntax-highlighter-javascript-regex?

like answering here on SO you'll probably need to have a raw input textarea that the user can type in, and a second field showing the highlighted syntax (otherwise you're going to have to strip out the highlighting when you accept the text)

Comment: This is not what I need. I want something that the user types in then submits a form

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of them

[1] : http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

[2] : http://www.textpad.com/